# FFMpeg runnig example for creating video from images

Tags: android, image-processing, ffmpeg

I have google a lot but not found any running example for creating video from images. 
I found that Ffmpeg can be used for creating video but because of lack of knowledge of `jni` I  could not understand how I can use `Ffmpeg` lib. Please suggest me how I can create video from Images. How I can use `Ffmpeg` for the same or any other running example. Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

Ffmpeg / jni on android is pretty involved, lots of learning curve to go up.

As an alternate, you might consider uploading from phone to a cloud instance and running an ffmpeg binary on the cloud instance to create your video from a series of photos ( and audio track ).

https://trac.ffmpeg.org/wiki/Create%20a%20video%20slideshow%20from%20images

above link for video from pics which you would put to a temp directory on the cloud instance for access by ffmpeg.

you can add audio with 2nd input file and with audio parms...

```
-acodec aac -ac 2 -ar 48000 -ab 192k
```

if you want to work with ffmpeg on android , go to gitub , search 'android-ffmpeg' and choose a project with big audience numbers.